# Ensure that make is invoked from a specific directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like all my recipes to be executed from a specific directory, the directory where the `Makefile` is located.

This is the default behaviour when invoking `make` without options, but an user could always run :

```
(cd /somewhere; make -f /path/to/directory/Makefile)
```

To ensure that `make` working directory is the same as the directory where the `Makefile` is located, there are multiple solutions :

- run `make` without options (default), from this specific directory (`cd /path/to/directory; make`)
- use `make -C /path/to/directory`
- `cd` to `/path/to/directory` for each recipe, like this :

```
MAKEFILE_DIR_LOCATION := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

a:
    cd ${MAKEFILE_DIR_LOCATION} && do_something_from_makefile_folder

b:
    cd ${MAKEFILE_DIR_LOCATION} && do_another_thing_from_makefile_folder
```

The problem is that the first two solutions requires actions from the user invoking the Makefile, while the last one clutters the `Makefile`.

Is there a prettier way to ensure that all recipes are executed from the directory where the `Makefile` is located?

#### Extra solution (does not work)

I also thought comparing the working directory (`$(shell pwd)`) to `${MAKEFILE_DIR_LOCATION}`, and exit if it does not match (at least to warn the user that `make` is not correctly invoked), but I can't find how to do this. I tried :

```
MAKEFILE_DIR_LOCATION := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
WORKING_DIR := $(shell pwd)

ifneq (${MAKEFILE_DIR_LOCATION}, ${WORKING_DIR})
@error "Please run make from the directory of the Makefile, or use make -C"
endif

a:
    do_something_from_makefile_folder

b:
    do_another_thing_from_makefile_folder
```

But I got a `missing separator` error (line `@error`), or a `recipe commences before first target` if `@error` line is indented.

Comment: ’*Is there a prettier way to ensure that all recipes are executed from the directory where the `Makefile` is located?*’ That’s the default behaviour. Are you seeing anything to suggest otherwise?

Comment: It's always possible for a user to run `(cd /somewhere; make -f /path/to/directory/Makefile)`. Then, working directory will be `/somewhere` instead of `/path/to/directory`. I'll edit my question with this to clarify.

Comment: Well yeah, with `-f` (which you didn’t mention in the question) there’s that ‘problem’. But if a user does that I’d expect them to know what they’re doing. Is that really something you have to deal with?

Comment: Sorry about not including this in the question, I just edited it. Since I don't have control over the users behaviour, I would like to at least throw an error if they are doing stupid things (meaning working directory is different from the path where the `Makefile` is located).

Comment: IMHO that’s not your job (without knowing much about the situation). If that’s an issue, then is your next worry ‘*What if a user copies the Makefile somewhere else?*’ or even ‘*What if a user edits the Makefile and it stops working?*’? I don’t think anyone expects a Makefile to be used that way (unless it’s explicitly documented). Draw the line here. Again, *IMHO*.

Comment: Yes you're probably right, but since it is possible to use `-f` (valid option), I would have expected something to prevent its usage. Note that I'm talking about `-f` option, but there may be other ways I don't know of to bypass the behaviour I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the question you asked without commenting on whether it's a good idea or not, I'm not sure where you found this syntax:

```
@error "Please run make from the directory of the Makefile, or use make -C"
```

but it's definitely wrong.  `error` is a make function, so you want this:

```
$(error Please run make from the directory of the Makefile, or use make -C)
```

Comment: Of course! That was a silly mistake... I'll accept this answer. However, may I please have your opinion if doing this is a good idea or not? Or, as @Biffen states in the comments, do you think checking the current working directory is unnecessary?

Comment: I personally have never bothered to do something like that in any of my makefiles.  In fact I don't know of anyone who uses `make -f` by hand; it's mainly used in scripts and recursive makefiles etc.  Most people just assume that there exists a `Makefile` in their current directory and it will do whatever is appropriate for that directory (and subdirectories).  However, if there's something destructive that could happen if the makefile runs in the wrong directory (it could delete a bunch of files or something) then I see no reason not to be extra careful and check.

Answer (score 2):

A variant on your last attempt would re-invoke Make in the correct directory, with the same target:

```make
ifneq (${MAKEFILE_DIR_LOCATION},${WORKING_DIR})

%:
    $(MAKE) -C ${MAKEFILE_DIR_LOCATION} $@

.PHONY: %

else

## rest of Makefile rules

endif
```